# Can Qt arrange for QObject* to be set to nullptr when QObject is destroyed?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Qt framework has an [signal for all `QObject`s which is emmited before destruction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) of that `QObject`. This event can be used to have some `QObject*` variable automatically emptied when the object it points to is destroyed.

But to do this, you need to employ relatively lot of code. You would need to register a signal and link it up to the variable. Not very convenient in my opinion.

Can I have it arranged (by Qt) that a pointer to `QObject` is cleared automatically when `QObject` is destroyed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not with a raw pointer, no, but Qt supplies a templated [QPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html) class that does exactly what you are describing.